# SimplePickerElement in MvvmCross - blank in iOS7

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got an MvvmCross app that was working fine until iOS 7 came out - in a `UIDialogController`, I have a few `SimplePickerElement`s. In iOS7 (even in the simulator), when the screen scrolls to the element, the screen is completely blank.

I've got the source code and would be happy to play around with it but I have no idea where to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed a similar issue for date and time pickets recently - it's to do with the transparency and default font colour of the new ios7 Pickers. I suspect this problem will be similar.

That issue was https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/458 - you can see the commit that fixed it linked there - it's a quick change to the background colour.

Comment: Thanks Stuart - I've implemented the changes in source code I copied from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/162a816d148df224df0b8f635aeafe30c0910de9/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Touch/Elements/SimplePickerElement.cs - could we get it implemented in that code for real, too?

Comment: We accept pull requests -'either edit the code on your box or online using github - eg https://github.com/blog/844-forking-with-the-edit-button

Comment: thanks stuart - this is the first time i've used github to contribute, hope i did it right! https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/469